# Complex loading page animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, pageload

Before you read the rest **this might be considered a broad question**.
I'm sorry if it is, but I have no other way to ask it than this.

So, I thought about a loading page animation, which **I** consider to be complex, but it may not be.

**What I want to achive is this:**

When the page loads (let's say the index page), what you would see would be **the point of view** of a person looking at his/her smartphone (or desktop monitor, depending on the media query). So you would basically see what you see right now. If you're on a chair or a sofa you see maybe your legs, your hands, the environment and of course the device. On that device you would see a miniature of your index page, like that person is looking at your website.

Ok, now when the page is loading you would see **a zoom** on the smartphone/desktop monitor like you are going *"into the content"* that's displayed on the screen of that person's smartphone/desktop monitor, and when it's completely loaded you see the actual website fully displayed on your device.

In other words, in the animation, that person's device becomes your device. Hope I was clear enough.

**POSSIBLE SOLUTIONS I THOUGHT ABOUT**

1. Putting a screenshot of the index page on the animation's device and then using `transform: scale();` for the zoom, but how could I *get rid* of the animation's content once the page is fully loaded, and then have the actual website displayed?
2. Having the entire `<body>` element zoomed out using `transform: scale();` and positioned on the person's device, and when the page id loaded using `transform: scale();` again to zoom in to the full viewport's size.

**Note** that I listed only CSS solutions, because I just started learning JS.

**IMPORTANT**: I don't want nobody to write that code for me. I only want to know if there's a solution, and if the solutions I thought about could work. Or, if I should use JS or other stuff I'm not aware about, in order to achive this animation.

Comment: I think you could do a wrapper around whole page content. It would have the image of the smartphone etc as a background. The content should be `scale()`d to fit the smartphone screen. It should scale up to it's original page after some event on the page. I think that loading can be really fast and user would see rather a strange flicker than a nice loading effect. Maybe set a timeout in JavaScript? Let's say that after 2 seconds a function is called which will set `scale(1)` on the content root element.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to use your solution. If I would use it when the page loads, is there a way to have it happen only 1 time? Not everytime the user goes back and forth through the pages, it could become annoing that everytime you arrive on the homepage it pops up.

Comment: If you want it to happen for only 1 time in session or ever, you could use sessionStorage (the first scenario) or localStorage (the second scenario) to store a flag which would state that the effect has been used and shouldn't be displayed again. You could read that flag on the page load and set `scale(1)` immediately if it was present.

Comment: I think that most browsers store previous page/few pages and their states in memory, so the loading effect *probably* won't show in that case

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot, really! :) Is that achivable with JS? I mean the flag

Comment: Yes, you can use `localStorage.setItem('loaded', true)` to set that flag. Then, you can use `localStorage.getItem('loaded')` to get that flag. It will return either `undefined` (when that flag is not present) or `"true"` (when it is present). Keep in mind that `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` store only strings, that's why true => "true". `sessionStorage` has basically the same API. The difference is, that content's of `sessionStorage` are deleted after browser is closed and `localStorage` persists until removed by JS or by user

Answer (score 1):

> **POSSIBLE SOLUTIONS I THOUGHT ABOUT**
>
> 1. Putting a screenshot of the index page on the animation's device and
>    then using transform: scale(); for the zoom, but how could I get rid
>    of the animation's content once the page is fully loaded, and then
>    have the actual website displayed?

you can get rid of the animation's content once the page is fully loaded with the help of javascript:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  var AnimationContent= document.querySelector("#ID OF YOUR ANIMATION CONTENT");

  AnimationContent.remove();

  // or

  AnimationContent.style.display = "none";

});
```